# Unable to migrate using ModelState and ProjectState using of migrations API in Django 3.0.3

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I am using ProjectState to migrate to a new attributes of a table. I am trying to understand the ModelState and ProjectState using of migrations API in Django 3.0.3.

I am unable to migrate to the new state which has new fields. Can someone help me with the `ProjectState` and `ModelState` usage of what to apply for new model_definition migration to work? The following code does not migrate to DB but doesnt give any error.

I want to migrate from a DB table state to another state and there are some metadata `_meta`.

- The current DB state `model_state.fields` is:

  `[('id', <django.db.models.fields.AutoField>)]`
- The future DB state `model_state.fields` after adding `fields_attrs` migrations should be this using the `models_definition`:

  `[('id', <django.db.models.fields.AutoField>), ('name', <django.db.models.fields.CharField>)]`

Model Definition Code is:

model_config object is

```
{
 '__module__': 'testmodule', 'app_label': 'testmodule', 
 '__unicode__': <function ModelScript.model_create_config.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000221B6FBEF70>, 
 'attrs': {'name': <django.db.models.fields.CharField>}
}
```

model_definition is:

```
model_definition = type(
                model_item.table_name,
                # TODO: Put this into Database
                # model_config.get("extends"),
                bases,
                model_config
            )
```

This is the code I am using:

```
from django.db.migrations.state import ProjectState
from django.db.migrations.migration import Migration
from django.db.migrations.state import ModelState
from django.db.migrations import operations

# model_definition is coming from a function as the following object
model_definition = {'__module__': 'testmodule', 'app_label': 'testmodule', '__unicode__': <function ModelScript.model_create_config.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002047275FF70>, 'attrs': {'name': <django.db.models.fields.CharField>}, '__doc__': 'SampleModel(id)', '_meta': <Options for SampleModel>, 'DoesNotExist': <class 'testmodule.SampleModel.DoesNotExist'>, 'MultipleObjectsReturned': <class 'testmodule.SampleModel.MultipleObjectsReturned'>, 'id': <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000204727F9430>, 'objects': <django.db.models.manager.ManagerDescriptor object at 0x00000204727F9490>}

model_state = ModelState.from_model(model_definition)

# field_attrs are all the new fields to be migrated         
for k,v in field_attrs.items():
    model_state.fields.append((k, v))

# Create a fake migration with the CreateModel operation
cm = operations.CreateModel(name=model_state.name, fields=model_state.fields)

migration = Migration("fake_migration", model_state.app_label)
migration.operations.append(cm)

# SHOULD ProjectState be used for the new definition to be APPLIED to DB and HOW?
state = ProjectState()
with db_conn.schema_editor(collect_sql=True, atomic=migration.atomic) as schema_editor:
     # Following create_model also doesnot migrate to Mysql DB
     # Gives a Table exists Error even with root user of mysql
     # schema_editor.create_model(model_definition)

     # Following doesnot migrate to the new required state
     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor, collect_sql=True)
     # Following gives atomic transaction error if used along with atomic
     # following commit commented gives no error but doesnt migrate
     # db_conn.commit()
```

I have read this and using [How to programmatically generate the CREATE TABLE SQL statement for a given model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666334/how-to-programmatically-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-a-given-mode)

Any help or resource is welcome on this.

Update: I did try the test cases of Django and it didn't work programmatically. Do I have to use addfield categorically? Unsure of how to get this working. Both projectstate and model_create way is not working

Comment: Do you have a git repo I could look at that contains a *reproducible example*?   When starting from an initial migration, the code I provided works, so I assume the problem is with your migration graph.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you *need* to be using the *model metaclass*, ie. **[`ModelBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/658bcc16f1b814b3a063d3fa16fabaea8b471863/django/db/models/base.py#L72)**, and not **`type`**:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

model_definition = ModelBase(
    model_item.table_name,
    bases,
    model_config
)
```

Once you use the proper *metaclass*, you will likely receive a myriad of errors, since you are using many class attributes that **`ModelBase`** sets internally, and is not expecting you to set yourself.

Instead of dumping all the attributes that your model has, you should only set the attributes that **`ModelBase`** expects to be set on a traditional model, which includes:

- **`__module__`** and **`__qualname__`**
- model fields
- custom managers or querysets
- model methods
- model **`Meta`**

Everything else should be omitted.

So for example, if you have a models that look like this, in the module **`myapp.models`**:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ModelWithMeta(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_table'
```

The dynamic version of these models need to look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

bases = (models.Model,)

Parent = ModelBase('Parent', bases, {
    '__module__': 'myapp.models',
    '__qualname__': 'Parent',
    'name': models.CharField(max_length=45),
})

Child = ModelBase('Child', bases, {
    '__module__': 'myapp.models',
    '__qualname__': 'Child',
    'name': models.CharField(max_length=45),
    'parent': models.ForeignKey('myapp.Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE),
})

ModelWithMeta = ModelBase('ModelWithMeta', bases, {
    '__module__': 'myapp.models',
    '__qualname__': 'ModelWithMeta',
    'Meta': type('Meta', (), {'db_table': 'some_table'}),
})
```

I don't understand the purpose of your migration code, so I will assume that it was a hack in attempt to get the dynamic models working, which means you can probably throw it out altogether and use the builtin migration loader, ie:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations myapp && python3 manage.py migrate myapp
```

I you aren't familiar with python **[`metaclasses`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)**, I'd recommend reading up on them, since it's a prerequisite to understand my code.

Comment: Nice explaination. I really appreciate you taking the time for this. I will try this w/ ModelState to migrate. I have this structure only that I dont have qualname instead I have app_label & module_name. Let me try &explain this in a different way: I am able to use the app_label way(w/o qualname) to create a model. But when I try to migrate using create_model or CreateModel class to a db w/ an already created table, I am unable to get it apply migration. >> Anything, I am doing wrong w/ using CreateModel class or create_model function& migrations that it is not migrating to mysql db?

Comment: Right now, the ModelState is being fetched correct w/ the current code. It is not just migrating to DB w/ the new ProjectState using `CreateModel` class or create_model migration API even with ProjectState having right migration new state fields. I will also try the same code with ModelBase but right now it is not migrating to DB that is the issue

Comment: So frankly, the answer doesn't resolve the actual problem. Anything on the ProjectState and ModelState that I doing wrong or that I am doing wrong with create_model function? Do I have to use addfield and removefield explicitly? I was able to migrate using create_model  before. It stopped working suddenly and I am now scratching my head since 2 weeks

Comment: I just had an issue with reloading to show the admin registration to be right. I install uvicorn and gunicorn and it stopped working after the setup of the gunicorn server and running code with it. Now, even with default Dev server it doesn't work. Is it Django codebase issue? Doesn't seem. I tried testcase usages and didn't work with my code. Looks like my code. But still checking. I was able to migrate until this with this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222558/make-migrate-model-programmatically-and-reload-repopulate-django-application

Comment: @Gary Can you update your question with **exactly** how you tried to implement my answer?  The answer I provided *"works on my machine"*, so I don't really have an MRE to work with.

Comment: This is the actual question : `I am unable to migrate to the new state which has new fields. Can someone help me with the ProjectState and ModelState usage of what to apply for new model_definition migration to work. The following code does not migrate to DB but doesnt give any error.` No change.